# show that $\frac{R^4-R}{R^2+R+1}\le |\frac{z^4+iz}{z^2+z+1}| \le \frac{R^4+R}{(R-1)^2}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

show that $\frac{R^4-R}{R^2+R+1}\le |\frac{z^4+iz}{z^2+z+1}| \le \frac{R^4+R}{(R-1)^2}$

for all $z$ satisfying $|z|=R>1$

***My idea:***

$|\frac{z^4+iz}{z^2+z+1}| \le |\frac{|z^4|+|iz|}{|z^2|+|z|+1}|\le \frac{R^4+R}{R^2+R+1}  $

Comment: It is true that $|z^4 + iz| \leq |z^4| + |iz|$ but for the denominator, you need a *lower* bound in order to correctly bound from above the magnitude of the quotient (this is in reference to the idea you've shown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the denominator: $|z^{2}+z+1|\geq|z|^{2}-|z|-1=R^{2}-R-1\geq R_{2}-2R-1=(R-1)^{2}$, so $\dfrac{1}{|z^{2}+z+1|}\leq\dfrac{1}{(R-1)^{2}}$.

For the denominator again: $|z^{2}+z+1|\leq|z|^{2}+|z|+1=R^{2}+R+1$, so $\dfrac{1}{|z^{2}+z+1|}\geq\dfrac{1}{R^{2}+R+1}$.

For the numerator: $|z^{4}+iz|\geq|z|^{4}-|iz|=R^{4}-R$.

Comment: @user284331...can you please given hint for other part